# How can I multiply or divide every value in an column by 2 while ignoring blank cells using Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am modifying .csv files using Microsoft Excel and would like to be able to quickly multiply or divide all the values within columns by 2 in order to save myself time. At the same time I also wish to not touch any blank cells that exist within said columns so I do not mess up the formatting of said .csv files and cause errors once they are read by programs.

Comment: Please refer to Preston Maness's formulas, you can select the column includes cells where you want to display the calculation results, then enter the formula into Formula Bar, press **Ctrl** and **Enter** keys at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) function:

`=IF(A2="","",A2*2)`

An example:

[image]

The other column for Divide Result is

`=IF(B2 = "", "", B2/2)`

Comment: Assuming you are editing/saving the csv file and not xlsx, you could do this formula and "duplicate" your whole table with your multiplier next to the original data. Next, select all the new data and copy-paste over you existing data, but use paste as values. Now delete all formulas and "save as" csv for reuse in your other programs.